# If $a\neq 0 $ and $ab = ac \implies b=c$

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory

$F = R^2$

Let F be a field; $a,b,c \in F$

If $a \neq 0$, and $ab = ac \implies b =c$

Pf;

We know that there exists y s.t  $a \cdot y = 1$(Field Thm)

$$ay +ab = ay + ac$$
$$a(y +b) = a(y + c)$$
$$ y + b = y + c$$
$$ b =  c$$

Comment: please fix ur title

Comment: Do you mean if $a \neq 0$? because $x$ has nothing to do with the equation you write. Also, what structure are you working over (e.g. a field, an integral domain, an arbitrary ring?)

Comment: @KyleGannon sorry about that i updated it

Comment: Are we working with real numbers? Or at least in some integral domain?

Comment: If you have a multiplicative inverse you generally multiply by it, rather than adding something.

Comment: Just left-multiply by your $y$ and call it a day.

Comment: @Randall true didn't realize that

Comment: What do you mean by "$F=R^2$" and "Let $F$ be a field?" These together are somewhat confusing.

Comment: You've basically assumed what you are trying to prove when you assume that $a(y+b)=a(y+c)$ implies $y+b=y+c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that from the line $$a(y+b)=a(y+c)$$ that makes you conclude that $y+b=y+c$.

If you could have perform that trick from the beginning, you would have solved the problem directly.

Proposal:

From $ab=ac$, why not perform $y(ab)=y(ac)$.

Answer (score 3):

Saying $a(y+b)=a(y+c)\implies y+b=y+c$ uses the result which we are tasked to prove. Try the following. As long as $a,b,c\in R$ and $R$ is some integral domain we have:
$$\begin{align}ab=ac&\implies ab-ac=0\\&\implies a(b-c)=0\qquad~~~~~~~~~~\text{by distributivity}\\&\implies a=0\text{ or }b-c=0\qquad\text{since $R$ is an integral domain}\\&\implies b-c=0\qquad~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{since $a\neq 0$ by assumption}\\&\implies b=c\end{align}$$
Note that all fields are integral domains, so this surely works over some field $F$.